# If I don't have throttle body cleaner, what can I safely use as an alternative?

Tags: cleaning, throttle, throttle-body

Pretty much as the title states, I need to clean my throttle body, but I don't have any 'throttle body cleaner'.

Are there any other common solvents I could use instead, that would be both effective and safe on the throttle body? For example, brake, carburetor or MAF sensor cleaner?

Comment: Probably anything that lifts the dirt, does not damage any parts and dries without residue...

Comment: I always thought carburetor and throttle body cleaner were the same thing.  Bake cleaner works too.  Brake cleaner is good at not leaving any residue behind.